# Assigning variable as a HTML Image source path (<img src="variable_name">) in PHP?

Tags: php, html, image, variables

I am reading one image file which is stored in temporary directory.

```
<img width=400 height=400 align="bottom" src= " <?php echo $JobDir.'/venndiagram.png' ?>" alt="">
```

where `$JobDir` is PHP variable having image path. But above does not work.

Comment: There are extra spaces between `src` and `<?php`. You must remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **`src`** like this

```
<img width=400 height=400 align="bottom" src="<?php echo $JobDir ?>/venndiagram.png" alt="">
```

**If your `$JobDir` is**

```
$JobDir = 'path/to/folder/'; # then remove slash(/) on here >/ve
                         ^
$JobDir = 'path/to/folder'; # then Just keep it as it is
                         ^
```

Comment: Sorry it does not work for me.

Comment: `echo $JobDir` and post the output here

Comment: /home/man/tmpdata/145357787491188/

Comment: so remove ***Slash*** on here `/venndiagram` and try once

Comment: That's not going to be a valid location for Http requests.

Comment: @ManishKumar and your URL path is incorrect. If in host there is no path like that. Check once. its wrong

Comment: it always matches from root i guess but i want to store it temporarily and want to use it.

Comment: So use that in your project folder. Not outside the folder

Answer (score 1):

i think abdulla's answer was right. just he forgot to give semicolon after the variable

```
<img width=400 height=400 align="bottom" src="<?php echo $JobDir; ?>/venndiagram.png" alt="">
```

Comment: semicolon  is  not required in this manner

Comment: but it gives error many times.

Answer (score -1):

Use echo instead:

```
<img width=400 height=400 align="bottom" src="<?=$JobDir?>/venndiagram.png" alt=""></i>
```

<sub>*Note: If you don't have [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled you will have to use `<?php echo $JobDir?>`*</sub>

Comment: This gives the error of short tag using unless you have allowed it

Comment: It does nto wrok also. image is there but it cannot read it.